# How can I go to settingScreen when I click the drawerItem(setting) in DrawerContent at Scaffold in Fun ListScreen?

Tags: navigation, android-jetpack-compose

How can I go to settingScreen when I click the drawerItem(setting) in DrawerContent at Scaffold in Fun ListScreen?

I want to open drawer from listscreen and from the drawer when I click the setting icon, I want to see settingScreen.

I have added the class and function that are involved with the question.

Here I added the screens that will appear on the screen. I deleted other screens that are not relavant from the question.

**Screen class**

```
class Screens (navController: NavHostController) {


    val setting: () -> Unit = {
        navController.navigate(route = "setting/${Action.SETTING}") {
            popUpTo(SETTING_SCREEN) { inclusive = true }
        }
    }
}
```

**enum class**

Here are the defined Actions of ToDo App.

```
enum class Action {
    ADD,
    UPDATE,
    DELETE,
    DELETE_ALL,
    UNDO,
    SETTING,
    NO_ACTION
}
```

**SetupNavigation**
Here the starting point of screen is Splash Screen.

```
@Composable
fun SetupNavigation(
    navController: NavHostController,
    viewModel: ViewModel,
    onNavigationIconClick: () -> Unit,
) {
    val screen = remember(navController) {
        Screens(navController = navController)
    }

    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = SPLASH_SCREEN
    ) {
        settingComposable(
            navigateToSettingScreen = screen.setting,
            viewModel = viewModel
        )
    }
}
```

**SettingComposable**

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.settingComposable(
    navigateToSettingScreen: () -> Unit,
    viewModel: ViewModel
) {
    composable(
        route = Constants.SETTING_SCREEN,
    ) {
        SettingsScreen(viewModel = viewModel, navigateToSettingScreen = navigateToSettingScreen)
    }
}
```

**empty Settings Screen**

```
@Composable
fun SettingsScreen(
    viewModel : ViewModel,
    navigateToSettingScreen: () -> Unit
) {

}
```

**DrawerContent**

```
@Composable
fun DrawerContent(
    viewModel: ViewModel,
    gradientColors: List<Color> = listOf(Color(0xFFDAB74E), Color(0xFFC46608)),
    navigateToSettingScreen: () -> Unit

) {
          DrawerItem(icon = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_settings), label = "Settings")  {
              viewModel.drawerBarState.value = DrawerBarState.SETTINGS
              navigateToSettingScreen()
          }
      }
    }
}
```

**ListScreen**

```
@Composable
fun ListScreen(
    navigateToTaskScreen: (taskId: Int) -> Unit,
    viewModel: ViewModel,
    onNavigationIconClick: () -> Unit,
) {
    Scaffold(

        drawerContent = {
            DrawerContent(viewModel = viewModel,
                navigateToSettingScreen = {}
            )
        },
```

I tried to connect the logic by using navigateToSettingScreen = {}, but I don't know how to connect.

**ListScreen**

```
@Composable
fun ListScreen(
    navigateToTaskScreen: (taskId: Int) -> Unit,
    viewModel: ViewModel,
    onNavigationIconClick: () -> Unit,
) {
    Scaffold(

        drawerContent = {
            DrawerContent(viewModel = viewModel,
                navigateToSettingScreen = {}
            )
        },
```